# How to change guzzle properties from goutte?

Tags: php, guzzle, goutte

```
<?php
require_once '/var/www/goutte.phar';
 use Goutte\Client; 


 $guzzle = parent::getClient(); //You'll want to pull the Guzzle client out of Goutte to inherit its defaults
$guzzle->setDefaultOption('verify', '/path/to/cacert.pem'); //Set the certificate at @mtdowling recommends
$client->setClient($guzzle); //Tell Goutte to use your modified Guzzle client 

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://ocean.ac-guadeloupe.fr/publinet/resultats'); //Proceed as you were
var_dump($crawler);
?>
```

When i run the above code I get the error "Cannot access parent:: when no class scope is active". So how to access Guzzle properties from Goutte?

Answer (score 0):

The start of the sample seems to assume you are writing an extension of the Goutte Client class. If you are just using the class, the snippet is more like:

```
$client = new Client();
$guzzle = $client->getClient(); //You'll want to pull the Guzzle client out of Goutte to inherit its defaults

$guzzle->setDefaultOption('verify', '/path/to/cacert.pem'); //Set the certificate at @mtdowling recommends
$client->setClient($guzzle); //Tell Goutte to use your modified Guzzle client 

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://ocean.ac-guadeloupe.fr/publinet/resultats'); //Proceed as you were
var_dump($crawler);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted. I was having issues getting goutte to bypass some ssl self cert issues. I followed what you said, but changed ('verify', 'path/to/cert') to ('verify', false) and it worked like a charm.